# How can I make a '%search%' in two tables at two specific columns?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

I have two tables:

Table 1:

> ID int auto_increment
>
> person_name varchar
>
> person_nickname varchar

Table 2:

> ID int auto_increment
>
> company_name varchar
>
> company_nickname varchar

I want to search both tables, at both fields (Not the ID), with one query only.

My search form looks like this:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
     <input type="text" name="search" />
     <button type="submit" title="Pesquisar" class="btn-search"></button>
 </form>
```

Basically what I want is to make a search field that will search in this two particular tables fields.

Comment: Why do you want only 1 query? Also, what do you want your result set to look like?

Comment: use a tool like MYSql-front, connect the db and create a query using tables, you can get the query string, can learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want a single query, but I'm going to try to give you an idea of a way to accomplish it.

You aren't specifying what type of result you want, so here is my shot at what you might want. I do want to point out that `LIKE` has a rather poor performance, so my code below is going to run poorly the bigger the db gets.

**I'm not sure this is the proper way to do it**, but something like this should work:

```
(SELECT 'table1' AS 'table', id, person_name AS 'name', person_nickname AS 'nickname'
  FROM table1
  WHERE (person_name LIKE '%search%' OR person_nickname LIKE '%search%'))
UNION 
(SELECT 'table2' AS 'table', id, company_name AS 'name', company_nickname AS 'nickname'
  FROM table2
  WHERE (company_name LIKE '%search%' OR company_nickname LIKE '%search%'))
```

This will return results for `Search=Dave` like:

- table: table1, id: 5, name: Dave Jones, nickname: Popeye
- table: table1, id: 3, name: David Test, nickname: Dave
- table: table2, id: 5, name: CompanyDave, nickname: Petersons
- table: table2, id: 3, name: MyCompany, nickname: Davestest

More info on UNION at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Thanks, I 'll try that. I need that search for a simple clients and companys search in my db. You said, as bigger the db gets the poorly this code will run, why is that? How can I make it better? 
Anyway, thanks a lot.